nginx: make client verification optional but retrieve its Cert SN
I want to provide an endpoint that does not necessarily verify the client cert but does still retrieve its SN so that I can do something with that (i.e. check if the SN is in a list of allowed ones, although the cert is expired).
Unfortunately nginx seems to skip everything client cert related when I set the ssl_verify_client to off, so I am not able to retrieve any cert information:

server { # Resource "/sos"
    listen       8083 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    error_log stderr debug;

    ssl_certificate /opt/mtls_proxy/server-cert-chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/mtls_proxy/server-key.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    # DISable verification
    ssl_verify_client off;
    ssl_client_certificate /opt/mtls_proxy/client-cas.pem;
    ssl_verify_depth 0;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;

    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA256;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_crl /opt/mtls_proxy/crls.pem;

    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        set $escaped_client_cert $ssl_client_escaped_cert;

        # Default : Reject every connect attemp other than specified by Cert Serial (see nginx.conf)
        if ($reject) {
            return 403;
        }

        client_body_buffer_size 100k;
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        proxy_pass http://{{ or (env "SERVICE_HOSTNAME") "service" }}:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

       ...

The idea was to allow all connections and then use sth. like
    map $ssl_client_fingerprint $reject {
      default 0;
      <allowed-sn> 0;
    }

to select the certs that are nevertheless allowed to connect.
When setting ssl_verify_client to optional or optional_no_ca the expired cert gets rejected.
How can I retrieve the cert SN although ssl_verify_client is off?
